# wcf upload stream - The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis-7, streaming

I investigate lots of similar question but I cannot solve my problem!

I am tring to send an XML file to server and get response as an XML file via a function.

**I am able to send XML file up to 48Kb but not larger files!**

While developing my web service and client, I used [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP)

Additionally, I made some changes on ISS setting as follows:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/uploadreadaheadsize 10485760

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize:"10485760"  /commit:apphost
```

I added `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="10485760" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" executionTimeout="36000"/>` in service web.config file

and `<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10485760"/>
  </system.web>` in client's app.config file

I implemented binding and service configuration in service's web.config file as follows:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
      openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
      contract="IService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

in client's configuration in App.config:

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
                openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed"
                messageEncoding="Text">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**Do you have any idea about why I cannot send a file whose size is more than 48KB?**

Comment: do your client have a different assembly for WCF call? Or does the client assembly directly call WCF service?

Comment: What is the error you get when sending file > 48k ?

Comment: I added WCF Service in client application as Service referance

I got the error " The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request"

Comment: usually you get this error when maxRequestLength is not configured properly, but it looks like you are doing it correctly. Are you sure you configured the maxRequestLength on the IIS web application where you are consuming the service as well?

Comment: my service is working under Default Web Site.
but there are other web services under Default Web Site.
Can they conflict? 

for configuring maxRequestLength on ISS I used that comments

cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/uploadreadaheadsize 10485760

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize:"10485760"  /commit:apphost

As I investigated uploadReadAheadSize specifies the maxRequestLength

Comment: [uploadReadAheadSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525310(v=VS.90).aspx) is only the buffer, how is it related to maxRequestLength? Please check your iis settings for maxRequestLength.

Comment: Where/How can I checked it?

Comment: Directly from IIS as in http://i47.tinypic.com/28bttn7.jpg

Comment: Thank, I checked it and updated it to 2147483647.
however my problem is not solved :S

Comment: No need to try 2147483647, just try with some big size like 250000(for 250MB approx.) Also woth checking [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/09/24/from-iis6-maxrequestlength-to-iis7-maxallowedcontentlengthfile-specifying-maximum-file-upload-size.aspx) if you are using IIS 7+

Comment: I checked the site that "Flowerking" sent but nothing changes!

Answer (score 0):

I added the code below in web.cofing file than the problem was solved :D

```
  <protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"/>
</protocolMapping>
```